# Trying to connect to gorm with oracle driver fails, how can I fix it?

Tags: oracle, go, go-gorm

After using raw sql, I am trying to use gorm. There is a godorer library, but in a situation where the go-ora library must be used, the following error is returned when the code is executed. I do not know what the problem is.

```
package database

import (
    "os"

    "github.com/cengsin/oracle"
    go_ora "github.com/sijms/go-ora"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)
....

    db, err := gorm.Open(oracle.Open(go_ora.BuildJDBC(databaseInfo.Username, databaseInfo.UserPassword, databaseInfo.ConnectString, urlOptions)), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    return db
}
```

error is

```
# github.com/cengsin/oracle
../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/cengsin/oracle@v1.0.0/create.go:137:39: not enough arguments in call to field.Set
        have (reflect.Value, any)
        want (context.Context, reflect.Value, interface{})
../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/cengsin/oracle@v1.0.0/oracle.go:53:59: unknown field 'WithReturning' in struct literal of type callbacks.Config
../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/cengsin/oracle@v1.0.0/oracle.go:101:36: cannot convert 0 (untyped int constant) to *int
../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/cengsin/oracle@v1.0.0/oracle.go:103:37: cannot use limit (variable of type *int) as type int in argument to strconv.Itoa
failed to build, error: exit status 2
running...
panic: reflect: reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value

goroutine 1 [running]:
reflect.flag.mustBeAssignableSlow(0x103677e60?)
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/reflect/value.go:260 +0x74
reflect.flag.mustBeAssignable(...)
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/reflect/value.go:247
reflect.Value.Set({0x10361d5a0?, 0x140003107f8?, 0x103677e60?}, {0x10361d5a0?, 0x140001b71c8?, 0x1400029a7e0?})
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/reflect/value.go:2154 +0x54
gorm.io/gorm/schema.(*Field).setupValuerAndSetter.func6({0x1036fdbf0, 0x140001b6008}, {0x103677e60?, 0x140003107f8?, 0x0?}, {0x10360da40, 0x140001b71c8}, 0x14000310618)
        /Users/choiyunseok/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.24.3/schema/field.go:558 +0x658
gorm.io/gorm/schema.(*Field).setupValuerAndSetter.func9({0x1036fdbf0?, 0x140001b6008?}, {0x103677e60?, 0x140003107f8?, 0x1400029a7e0?}, {0x10360da40?, 0x140001b71c8?})
        /Users/choiyunseok/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.24.3/schema/field.go:714 +0x6c8
github.com/godoes/gorm-oracle.Create.func7(0x140002d01e0)
        /Users/choiyunseok/go/pkg/mod/github.com/godoes/gorm-oracle@v1.3.16/create.go:137 +0xf8
reflect.Value.call({0x10361a8a0?, 0x14000689140?, 0x103652ec0?}, {0x10311f3b6, 0x4}, {0x140005a9830, 0x1, 0x102fd53b4?})
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/reflect/value.go:584 +0x688
reflect.Value.Call({0x10361a8a0?, 0x14000689140?, 0x103652ec0?}, {0x140005a9830?, 0x103652ec0?, 0x140005ac0f0?})
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.19.3/libexec/src/reflect/value.go:368 +0x90
github.com/thoas/go-funk.ForEach({0x10360f580?, 0x140003109c0}, {0x10361a8a0?, 0x14000689140})
        /Users/choiyunseok/go/pkg/mod/github.com/thoas/go-funk@v0.9.3/scan.go:40 +0x4a4
github.com/godoes/gorm-oracle.Create(0x1400029a000)
        /Users/choiyunseok/go/pkg/mod/github.com/godoes/gorm-oracle@v1.3.16/create.go:130 +0xbec
gorm.io/gorm.(*processor).Execute(0x14000534500, 0x140006915f0?)
        /Users/choiyunseok/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.24.3/callbacks.go:130 +0x3e4
gorm.io/gorm.(*DB).Create(0x103677e60?, {0x103677e60?, 0x140003107f8})
        /Users/choiyunseok/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.24.3/finisher_api.go:24 +0xa8
github.com/sideweve/weveServerEcho/system/database.Setting()
        /Users/choiyunseok/project/weve_server_echo/system/database/setting.go:21 +0xd0
github.com/sideweve/weveServerEcho/system/server.Start()
        /Users/choiyunseok/project/weve_server_echo/system/server/server.go:29 +0x6c
main.main()
        /Users/choiyunseok/project/weve_server_echo/main.go:27 +0x1c
```

You must use go-ora, do you know how to run the code without errors in this situation? I would appreciate it if you could give me some advice.